# How to add item on top of listview and save it in database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to save data using listview and I want to store the next data at the top of the listview instead it is storing data in the bottom. Here's my DatabaseHelper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
private static final String COL1 = "ID";
private static final String COL2 = "name";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2 +" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addData(String item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item);


    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    //if data as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as top bottom middle etc with SQLite, although the order of insertions will generally/likely match the **rowid** column or an alias thereof (your **ID** column is an alias of the **rowid** column and as **AUTOINCREMENT** has been specified then a new insert will have a higher **rowid** then any that exist).

If you need data in a particular order then you use **ORDER BY** when extracting the data. In your case **`ORDER BY ID DESC`** should extract the latest first.

As the code you use to extract the data is not present the actual code to be used cannot be provided.